# What happens when transaction fails to be applied?

Tags: transactions, data

What happens when a network comes to a consensus about a transaction, but that transaction fails to get applied on **some** nodes but not **all** nodes?

A more concrete example is `createAccount` operation. When some nodes apply the operation and add a new account but some others don't, what happens? And I don't mean it in terms of bad quorum configurations. What happens when there's, for example, a database failure or any kind of systematic failure when applying operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for applying transactions are deterministic, so any validator that fails a transaction that should have succeeded is ill-behaved.  SCP survives ill-behaved nodes so long as there is a well-behaved quorum U in which nodes enjoy quorum intersection after removing all nodes not in U from everyone's quorum slices.

Comment: As a node that failed to apply a set of transactions without purposefully being malicious, what measurements are taken to roll back the changes or reapply the transactions?

Comment: If your node is faulty, it needs to be replaced.  But note that there's a distinction between just failing to apply transactions because you crashed, and falsely claiming that the transactions failed (and you increased sequence numbers, charged fees, etc.).  The former is self-correcting by restarting stellar-core, while the latter indicates your node is faulty and needs to be replaced.